# How to access outer class variable of same name?

Tags: java, encapsulation, inner-classes, nested-class

I have made an Outer and an Inner class. Both these classes have variable `int x`. How to access `x` of Outer class in inner class. `this.x` is not working.

```
class OuterClass {
int x,y;
private class InnerClass {
    private void printSum(int x,int y) {
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: OuterClass.this.x and OuterClass.this.y. OuterClass.this references the outer class.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try this :

```
   private void printSum(int x,int y) {
       OuterClass.this.x=x;
       OuterClass.this.y=y;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this you need to first instantiate the outer class, then the inner like so:

```
/* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    int x,y,sum;

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        //Create outer object
        Ideone ideOne = new Ideone();

        //instantiate inner object, and call method
        Ideone.InnerClass ic = ideOne.new InnerClass();
        ic.printSum(5,4);
    }


    private class InnerClass {
        private void printSum(int x,int y) {
            //reference the outer object instance
            Ideone.this.x=x;
            Ideone.this.y=y;
            Ideone.this.sum = x + y;
            System.out.println(Ideone.this.sum);
        }
    }
}
```

This has been tested here: http://ideone.com/e.js/DRIzSg

```
Output: 9
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `OuterClass.this.x`; `OuterClass.this` references the parent object (from whom the `InnerClass` object is spawned).

Consider the following overshadowing example posted in the official Oracle tutorial:

```
public class ShadowTest {

    public int x = 0;

    class FirstLevel {

        public int x = 1;

        void methodInFirstLevel(int x) {
            System.out.println("x = " + x);
            System.out.println("this.x = " + this.x);
            System.out.println("ShadowTest.this.x = " + ShadowTest.this.x);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        ShadowTest st = new ShadowTest();
        ShadowTest.FirstLevel fl = st.new FirstLevel();
        fl.methodInFirstLevel(23);
    }
}
```

with the output

```
x = 23
this.x = 1
ShadowTest.this.x = 0
```

`x = 23` refers to the local variable of the method `void methodInFirstLevel()`, `this.x = 1` refers to the public field `x` of the `FirstLevel` inner-class, and `ShadowTest.this.x = 0` refers to the public field `x` of the `ShadowTest` outer-class.

Answer (score -1):

Other way is to Make Outer class members as **protected**

```
public class OuterClass {

 protected int x=10,y=20;

private class InnerClass {

    private void printSum(int x1,int y1) {
        x=x1;
        y=y1;
    }

  }

 }
```